# ExtJs namespace alias

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there any way to give a namespace an alias?

ergo i want to do

```
Ext.ns ( 'somereallylongname' );
```

and then alias it to 'srln'
and be able to do

```
Ext.ns ( 'srln.panel');
```

and create it by

```
Ext.create('somereallylongname.panel');
```

Example is a bit contrived, but meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Ext.ns ( 'somereallylongname' );
var srln = somereallylongname;
```

added

make sure `srln` is in global scope